# Play DRM encrypted files in Videojs

Tags: video.js, drm

We have videojs in places and we have DRM media HLS videos basically , is there any sample to implement the same.

Answer (score 5):

DRM support in videojs is provided by a plugin - as mentioned in the videojs FAQ:

> Support for DRM video via a core plugin
>
> ```
>  videojs-contrib-eme
> ```

The plugin is available here: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-eme

This includes usage instructions and tests on major browsers.

Answer (score 3):

u can refer DRM in HLS stream in [videojs-contrib-hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) and [videojs-contrib-eme](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-eme)

And sample code as

```
 const options = {
     "preload": "auto",
     "width":"600 px",
     hls: {
       withCredentials: true
     },
     plugins: {
       videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
         // default: 'high',
         dynamicLabel: true
       }
     },
     html5: {
      nativeCaptions: false,
      dash: {
        setLimitBitrateByPortal: false,
        // setMaxAllowedBitrateFor: ['video', 2000]
      }
    }
  };
     videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.swf"
     video = videojs("your videotag id");
     video.src([
         {
           type: "application/x-mpegURL",
           src: "your url",
           keySystemOptions: [
{
  name: 'com.widevine.alpha',
  options: {
    serverURL: 'http://m.widevine.com/proxy'
  }
}
 ]

           }
       ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to add videojs-contrib-eme with CND you can checkout :
https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/videojs-contrib-eme